# Magento 2 How to correctly change the size of the minicart icon on the desktop?

Tags: magento-2.1, less, less-css

[image: example]

Copy theme Luma. 
I tried to find the correct solution in the documentation and found that this is done using `.lib-dropdown` in `app\design\frontend\Vendorname\default\Magento_Checkout\web\css\source\module\_minicart.less`. Also I could not understand how to remove: `.minicart-wrapper .block-minicart:before` and `.minicart-wrapper .block-minicart:after`.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this code

```
.minicart-wrapper .block-minicart:before,
.minicart-wrapper .block-minicart:after
{ display: none }
```

and to resize the shopping cart size set the font-size what ever you want to this "`.minicart-wrapper .action.showcart.active:before`" class. The default font-size is 22px.

Comment: Thank you! But it is assumed that the original code will be changed, and not a new one will be added. Thus, increasing the number of styles for one block.